# Maximize window with display style none WPF

Tags: wpf

I have created a WPF window with displaystyle = none and successfully displaying the task bar on bottom. I actually used the following code taken from one of the threads from stack overflow. Everything is fine, but i am facing a little problem that code is very bulky and displaying on each window when i create new window every time.

So i just need to create another class and try to inherit it in the window class just like following:

```
 public partial class CustomWindow1 : Window, clsMaxi
```

But unfortulately it does not recognize the clsMaxi class. I have to create many windows and on each window i dont want to have so much code, so thats why i need to create some separate class and then try to inhert.

Following is the complete code. So anyone please help me to organize this code so that i will not call it on each window everytime when i will create a new window, thanks in advance.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Interop;

private bool mRestoreIfMove = false;


public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}


void Window_SourceInitialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IntPtr mWindowHandle = (new WindowInteropHelper(this)).Handle;
    HwndSource.FromHwnd(mWindowHandle).AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(WindowProc));
}


private static System.IntPtr WindowProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
{
   switch (msg)
     {
        case 0x0024:
        WmGetMinMaxInfo(hwnd, lParam);
        break;
     }

        return IntPtr.Zero;
 }


private static void WmGetMinMaxInfo(System.IntPtr hwnd, System.IntPtr lParam)
{
     POINT lMousePosition;
     GetCursorPos(out lMousePosition);

     IntPtr lPrimaryScreen = MonitorFromPoint(new POINT(0, 0), MonitorOptions.MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY);
     MONITORINFO lPrimaryScreenInfo = new MONITORINFO();
     if (GetMonitorInfo(lPrimaryScreen, lPrimaryScreenInfo) == false)
     {
        return;
     }

     IntPtr lCurrentScreen = MonitorFromPoint(lMousePosition, MonitorOptions.MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);

     MINMAXINFO lMmi = (MINMAXINFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MINMAXINFO));

     if (lPrimaryScreen.Equals(lCurrentScreen) == true)
     {
            lMmi.ptMaxPosition.X = lPrimaryScreenInfo.rcWork.Left;
            lMmi.ptMaxPosition.Y = lPrimaryScreenInfo.rcWork.Top;
            lMmi.ptMaxSize.X = lPrimaryScreenInfo.rcWork.Right - lPrimaryScreenInfo.rcWork.Left;
            lMmi.ptMaxSize.Y = lPrimaryScreenInfo.rcWork.Bottom - lPrimaryScreenInfo.rcWork.Top;
     }
     else
     {
            lMmi.ptMaxPosition.X = lPrimaryScreenInfo.rcMonitor.Left;
            lMmi.ptMaxPosition.Y = lPrimaryScreenInfo.rcMonitor.Top;
            lMmi.ptMaxSize.X = lPrimaryScreenInfo.rcMonitor.Right - lPrimaryScreenInfo.rcMonitor.Left;
            lMmi.ptMaxSize.Y = lPrimaryScreenInfo.rcMonitor.Bottom - lPrimaryScreenInfo.rcMonitor.Top;
     }

     Marshal.StructureToPtr(lMmi, lParam, true);
}


private void SwitchWindowState()
{
   switch (WindowState)
   {
      case WindowState.Normal:
           {
              WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
              break;
           }
      case WindowState.Maximized:
           {
              WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
              break;
           }
    }
}


private void rctHeader_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ClickCount == 2)
    {
       if ((ResizeMode == ResizeMode.CanResize) || (ResizeMode == ResizeMode.CanResizeWithGrip))
        {
           SwitchWindowState();
        }

         return;
     }

     else if (WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
     {
        mRestoreIfMove = true;
        return;
     }

     DragMove();
}


private void rctHeader_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    mRestoreIfMove = false;
}


private void rctHeader_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   if (mRestoreIfMove)
   {
            mRestoreIfMove = false;

            double percentHorizontal = e.GetPosition(this).X / ActualWidth;
            double targetHorizontal = RestoreBounds.Width * percentHorizontal;

            double percentVertical = e.GetPosition(this).Y / ActualHeight;
            double targetVertical = RestoreBounds.Height * percentVertical;

            WindowState = WindowState.Normal;

            POINT lMousePosition;
            GetCursorPos(out lMousePosition);

            Left = lMousePosition.X - targetHorizontal;
            Top = lMousePosition.Y - targetVertical;

            DragMove();
    }
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool GetCursorPos(out POINT lpPoint);


[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr MonitorFromPoint(POINT pt, MonitorOptions dwFlags);

enum MonitorOptions : uint
{
        MONITOR_DEFAULTTONULL = 0x00000000,
        MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY = 0x00000001,
        MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST = 0x00000002
}


[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool GetMonitorInfo(IntPtr hMonitor, MONITORINFO lpmi);


[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct POINT
{
        public int X;
        public int Y;

        public POINT(int x, int y)
        {
            this.X = x;
            this.Y = y;
        }
}


[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MINMAXINFO
{
        public POINT ptReserved;
        public POINT ptMaxSize;
        public POINT ptMaxPosition;
        public POINT ptMinTrackSize;
        public POINT ptMaxTrackSize;
};


[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public class MONITORINFO
{
        public int cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MONITORINFO));
        public RECT rcMonitor = new RECT();
        public RECT rcWork = new RECT();
        public int dwFlags = 0;
}


[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RECT
{
        public int Left, Top, Right, Bottom;

        public RECT(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
        {
            this.Left = left;
            this.Top = top;
            this.Right = right;
            this.Bottom = bottom;
        }
}
```

Edit:
Please download a simple two page Sample Project in which i am struggling to achieve the desired behavior.

[Sample Project](https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=3C97297B44990FBF&resid=3C97297B44990FBF%21145&authkey=ANNpKcDn5lO51eY)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to create your base class:

```
public class Maxi : Window
{
    private bool mRestoreIfMove = false;

    private void Window_SourceInitialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IntPtr mWindowHandle = (new WindowInteropHelper(this)).Handle;
        HwndSource.FromHwnd(mWindowHandle).AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(WindowProc));
    }

    private static System.IntPtr WindowProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        switch (msg)
        {
            case 0x0024:
                WmGetMinMaxInfo(hwnd, lParam);
                break;
        }

        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }

    private static void WmGetMinMaxInfo(System.IntPtr hwnd, System.IntPtr lParam)
    {
        POINT lMousePosition;
        GetCursorPos(out lMousePosition);

        IntPtr lPrimaryScreen = MonitorFromPoint(new POINT(0, 0), MonitorOptions.MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY);
        MONITORINFO lPrimaryScreenInfo = new MONITORINFO();
        if (GetMonitorInfo(lPrimaryScreen, lPrimaryScreenInfo) == false)
        {
            return;
        }

        IntPtr lCurrentScreen = MonitorFromPoint(lMousePosition, MonitorOptions.MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);

        MINMAXINFO lMmi = (MINMAXINFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MINMAXINFO));

        if (lPrimaryScreen.Equals(lCurrentScreen) == true)
        {
            lMmi.ptMaxPosition.X = lPrimaryScreenInfo.rcWork.Left;
            lMmi.ptMaxPosition.Y = lPrimaryScreenInfo.rcWork.Top;
            lMmi.ptMaxSize.X = lPrimaryScreenInfo.rcWork.Right - lPrimaryScreenInfo.rcWork.Left;
            lMmi.ptMaxSize.Y = lPrimaryScreenInfo.rcWork.Bottom - lPrimaryScreenInfo.rcWork.Top;
        }
        else
        {
            lMmi.ptMaxPosition.X = lPrimaryScreenInfo.rcMonitor.Left;
            lMmi.ptMaxPosition.Y = lPrimaryScreenInfo.rcMonitor.Top;
            lMmi.ptMaxSize.X = lPrimaryScreenInfo.rcMonitor.Right - lPrimaryScreenInfo.rcMonitor.Left;
            lMmi.ptMaxSize.Y = lPrimaryScreenInfo.rcMonitor.Bottom - lPrimaryScreenInfo.rcMonitor.Top;
        }

        Marshal.StructureToPtr(lMmi, lParam, true);
    }

    private void SwitchWindowState()
    {
        switch (WindowState)
        {
            case WindowState.Normal:
                {
                    WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
                    break;
                }
            case WindowState.Maximized:
                {
                    WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
                    break;
                }
        }
    }

    internal void rctHeader_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ClickCount == 2)
        {
            if ((ResizeMode == ResizeMode.CanResize) || (ResizeMode == ResizeMode.CanResizeWithGrip))
            {
                SwitchWindowState();
            }

            return;
        }

        else if (WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
        {
            mRestoreIfMove = true;
            return;
        }

        DragMove();
    }


    internal void rctHeader_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        mRestoreIfMove = false;
    }

    internal void rctHeader_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (mRestoreIfMove)
        {
            mRestoreIfMove = false;

            double percentHorizontal = e.GetPosition(this).X / ActualWidth;
            double targetHorizontal = RestoreBounds.Width * percentHorizontal;

            double percentVertical = e.GetPosition(this).Y / ActualHeight;
            double targetVertical = RestoreBounds.Height * percentVertical;

            WindowState = WindowState.Normal;

            POINT lMousePosition;
            GetCursorPos(out lMousePosition);

            Left = lMousePosition.X - targetHorizontal;
            Top = lMousePosition.Y - targetVertical;

            DragMove();
        }
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool GetCursorPos(out POINT lpPoint);


    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr MonitorFromPoint(POINT pt, MonitorOptions dwFlags);

    enum MonitorOptions : uint
    {
        MONITOR_DEFAULTTONULL = 0x00000000,
        MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY = 0x00000001,
        MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST = 0x00000002
    }


    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool GetMonitorInfo(IntPtr hMonitor, MONITORINFO lpmi);


    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct POINT
    {
        public int X;
        public int Y;

        public POINT(int x, int y)
        {
            this.X = x;
            this.Y = y;
        }
    }


    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct MINMAXINFO
    {
        public POINT ptReserved;
        public POINT ptMaxSize;
        public POINT ptMaxPosition;
        public POINT ptMinTrackSize;
        public POINT ptMaxTrackSize;
    };


    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public class MONITORINFO
    {
        public int cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MONITORINFO));
        public RECT rcMonitor = new RECT();
        public RECT rcWork = new RECT();
        public int dwFlags = 0;
    }


    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RECT
    {
        public int Left, Top, Right, Bottom;

        public RECT(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
        {
            this.Left = left;
            this.Top = top;
            this.Right = right;
            this.Bottom = bottom;
        }
    }
}
```

Your main window contains no code but just inherits:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Maxi
{
    public MainWindow() { InitializeComponent(); }
}
```

Then it's simply a case of getting your XAML right - that means using the correct namespace to create on object of type base class (in this case *Maxi* instead of *Window*) - but specify your window i.e. class which inherits "Maxi" in the x:Class directive of your XAML's local:Maxi declaration.

```
<local:Maxi 
    x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
    Title="MainWindow" Background="AliceBlue" WindowStyle="None" Height="350" Width="525" SourceInitialized="Window_SourceInitialized">
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle Name="rctHeader" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" Fill="CadetBlue"
                   PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="rctHeader_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" 
                   PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="rctHeader_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp" 
                   PreviewMouseMove="rctHeader_PreviewMouseMove"/>
    </Grid>
</local:Maxi>
```

Comment: Thankyou for the reply, I implemented your code but i am facing following error: 'Wpf_Parent_Stype.CustomWindow1' must not specify different base classes. Please help...

Comment: The sample code I gave you has different names for the windows and base class.  You need to get the namings correct.  If you show your code I can help, but you're not showing it all at the moment.  You didn't even post the XAML originally!

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have edit my original question and upload a sample project (Visual studio 2012). Please help...

Comment: I implemented your code exactly you send me. When i was not successfully implemented i roll back all code and send you simply with default xaml code. If you UN comment my all code of MainWindow() and change clsMaxi to Window (inherit again to Window class) my code will start working..... You can please create a separate class and implement for me according to requirement, i shall b very thankful to you..... Iam new to wpf please help ....

Comment: Ok so I've fleshed out the base class "Maxi" in my updated answer - just use all the code I gave you and make sure references to WpfApplication3 are changed to WpfApplication1.

Comment: Wow thats magic, bundle of thanks, but i really need to clarify myself that whenever we create any window we have this line of code at line no 1: <Window x:Class="Wpf_Parent_Style.CustomWindow1"  and you change it to: <local:Maxi in my case,  Can you please explain difference between these two lines in my scenario and why we encapsulate all code into <local:Maxi> ALL XAML CODE HERE </local:Maxi>? Really appreciate your time and help... :)

Comment: <local:Maxi> is necessary because that is what you are creating ... an instance of the 'Maxi' control (which inherits Window - so IS a window, but with all that extra stuff you added).  x:Class is set not to Maxi but to your window(s) and you can create as many of them as you want as long as they inherit Maxi (which inherits Window).  It's basic inheritance stuff really.

Comment: You actually replace <Window> tag with <local:maxi>. As i understand, now i am using maxi class instead of window class, am i right? secondly what does it mean the word local at first line? sorry for my silly question again. I am new to WPF , thanks and so nice of you :).

Comment: "local" is the namespace where the "Maxi" object is defined.  "Maxi" inherits window.  I've explained this a few times now, I suggest you read some books or articles to learn the basics about namespaces, programming with C# and WPF.

Comment: Thankyou, my issue resolved and i will surely learn these things. I really appreciate your help :)